# Is it possible to customize user_entity table used by keycloak?

Tags: database, single-sign-on, keycloak, customization, keycloak-services

I'm trying to use keyClaok for SSO. I set up mysql instead of embedded h2 database in keycloak.

However, there is a problem. On udemy lecture, lecturer told that it's not recommanded to handle db- table(created by keycloak) directly.

If business needs application handles user's several attributes (like modifying user's deparment, position, age, profile_img) , how to develop this needs with database in keycloak?

If i choose to use keycloak, should i consider that
database (which application use) and the other database (which keycloak use) are apart? which means USER-DOMAIN is isolated from other domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. If the amount of data is not considerable and have a simple name=value structure, you can just use the user attribute in Keycloak. It's like a map of data attached to each user. The other solution is to keep the data in your own repository and implement a custom `UserStorageProvider` that queries your database to fetch users (including extra properties). Keycloak documentation already has [an example of this provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi).

Comment: I tried to implement UserStorageProvider with reference that you linked. but it's hard to apply the decription. Would you give me other reference like blog which show a implemented UserStrorageProvider?

Comment: I recommend you to check Thomas Zub's Twitter and Github page. He has quite good collection of examples about Keycloak. Including user storage provider:  https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-user-storage-provider-demo. Also Niko Köbler has a YouTube channel with a playlist dedicated to Keycloak: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNn3plN7ZiaowUvKzKiJjYfWpp86u98iY