# Adding custom user attribute in keycloak using spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, customization, user-management

We can add users in keycloak from spring boot application using org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation. but if we want to add a custom user attribute in keycloak using UserRepresentation then UserRepresentation does not allow us to add custom attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to customize user\_entity table used by keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539494/is-it-possible-to-customize-user-entity-table-used-by-keycloak)

Answer (score 3):

Keycloak does allow you to add custom attributes to the user with the help of `org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation`.

```
public void addCustomAttributesToUser(Map<String, List<String>> customAttributes, String userId) {
    UserResource userResource = realmResource.users().get(userId);
    UserRepresentation userRepresentation = userResource.toRepresentation();
    userRepresentation.setAttributes(customAttributes);
    userResource.update(userRepresentation);
}
```